# Convert tiled image array into single image array with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I followed the process here: [How to Split Image Into Multiple Pieces in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953373/how-to-split-image-into-multiple-pieces-in-python) for splitting an image into MxN number of images. I have a 5490x5490 that I split into 100 pieces by using the following:

```
M = im.shape[0]//10
N = im.shape[1]//10
tiles = [im[x:x+M,y:y+N] for x in range(0,im.shape[0],M) for y in range(0,im.shape[1],N)]
```

The shape of tiles is:

```
np.array(tiles).shape
(100,549,549)
```

I cannot figure out how to put them back together as one and reshape does not put them back together in the right order.

Answer (score 0):

Found it after taking a break: [How to mosaic arrays using numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48846876/how-to-mosaic-arrays-using-numpy)

```
nd_arr = np.array(tiles)
nd_arr = nd_arr.reshape(10, 10, 549, 549)
nd_arr = nd_arr.swapaxes(1,2)
final = nd_arr.reshape(5490, 5490)
```

I can verify by:

```
(final == NDVI).sum()
30140100
```